# Расширенный поиск по нескольким параметрам

Tags: ajax, php, search, mysql

Добрый день, хэшкодеры. Проблема в следующем: нужно создать поиск по нескольким параметрам (пример  по ссылке http://auto.ria.ua/). Кто может подсказать какие нибудь материалы, шаблоны и т.д.?

Answer (score 2):

Могу рассказать, как я решал данную задачу. Для примера, создаем четыре таблицы: **products** (id_prod, prod_name, и т.д.), **prop_type** (id_pt, pt_name), **prop_val** (id_pv, id_pt, pv_name) и **filter_data** (id_product, id_prop_type, id_prop_val).

С первой таблицей всё понятно. Во второй храним названия групп фильтров (Марка, Модель, etc.), в третьей - свойства/значения каждой из групп ("**Марка**": *BMW*, *Audi*, *ЗаЗ*. "**Модель**" -> для BMW: *315*,*X5*,*Z3*; для Audi: *A1*,*100*; для ЗаЗ: *1102 Таврия*, *969*, *Горбатый* ;) и так дальше). Ну, а в четвертой таблице держим "связку" id продукта -> id группы фильтра -> id значение фильтра. Связь таблиц, можно представить таким образом:

[image]

Когда пользователь выбрал нужные параметры, мы сначала отбираем id продуктов (**id_products**) из таблицы **filter_data** по совпавшим значениям и соответственно им выводим товар из таблицы **products**.

Comment: очень интересно, спасибо !